# PHP. If field is empty - delete row

Tags: php, arrays

At the moment I use the following: 
I make a selection from the mysql and generate an xml-file:

```
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

      $xml .= "<Name>".$r['name']."</Name>";
      $xml .= "<Telephone>".$r['work']."</Telephone>";
    }
```

In a normal situation, I get this

```
<Name>Name Surname</Name>
<Telephone>111</Telephone>
```

But if the field of number is not filled, in the generated file it will be received so:

```
<Name>Name Surname</Name>
<Telephone></Telephone>
```

How to delete the entire block (Both name and phone) if the field with the phone number is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add nothing to `$xml` when field is empty:

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    if (!empty($r['work'])) {
      $xml .= "<Name>".$r['name']."</Name>";
      $xml .= "<Telephone>".$r['work']."</Telephone>";
    }
}
```

Or even modify your sql-query to select only values where `work` field is not empty:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3
FROM `some_table`
WHERE `work` <> ''
```

In this case you can leave your php-code as is.